# Why using Gstreamer for OpenCV backend?

Tags: opencv, gstreamer

I'm doing some tutorials on Gstreamer, and I come to wonder why people use Gstreamer backend for their OpenCV projects.

Is it because it's faster than the normal `Videocapture()`?

Or does it use hardware acceleration, like Cuda?

I don't know how `Videocapture()` works exactly, so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It does the fetch and decoding of the frames in the background, and it does use hardware acceleration for the encoding/decoding if available and set up properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1 - "why people use Gstreamer backend for their OpenCV projects"***

There is not a default backend api for gstreamer. Default backend enumerator of `VideoCapture` is `CAP_ANY`. As the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html) says:

> OpenCV automatically selects and uses first available backend
> (apiPreference=cv::CAP_ANY).

***2 - "Is it because it's faster than the normal Videocapture()?"***

There is no normal(default) backend api as explained before. Speed comparison also can be changable api to api. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d) is the all backend api for `VideoCapture`

***3 - "Or does it use hardware acceleration, like Cuda?"***

Cuda doesn't use gstreamer, it is compatible with ffmpeg.

For detailed information about streaming methodology of opencv, you can check [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html).